# C: Use pointer to access two dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, comparison

```
int main() {

char test [2][4]= {"BbBa","CBAD"} ; /*two dimensional array */
char ch = 'A'; /* match this character */
char *temp = &test; /* pointer to array */
int i=0;

if (temp[1][2] == ch){ /* if match to ch will print Yes */
    printf("Yes");
}
else{
    printf("No.");
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Hi all, it is a question about create pointer to an two dimensional array and then do comparison. 
In one dimensional, I use `temp = &test` and it's success, but it's not working for two dimensional.
How to access the array content by using pointer?
Thank you.

Comment: `char*` is the wrong type for `temp`. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: Try `char *temp = &test[0][0];` to create a pointer to the first string or `temp = &test[1][0];` to point to the 2nd string. Access with `if (temp[2] == ch)` This will acces 3rd char pointed by `temp`. Remember that there is no space for null terminator (see my note below). `char test [2][4]= {"BbBa","CBAD"} ;` is wrong because there is no space for string terminating NULL. You must allow space as in `char test [2][5]= {"BbBa","CBAD"} ;` the fifth char is for the terminating NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `temp` as a pointer to an array:

```
char (*temp)[4] = test;
```

This works because in most contexts an array is converted into a pointer to its first element.  And since `test` is an array of `char[4]` of size 2, a pointer to it is of type `char(*)[4]`.

Comment: OH! it works! Thank you!! I have another question. What if create the pointer in a function? such as 
functionA (char test){ 
 (*temp)[4] = test ; } 
 char test [2][4]= {"BbBa","CBAD"} ;  
any different of two dimensional array and pointer in different level? Thank you.